# Gson, JSON and the subtleties of LinkedTreeMap

Tags: java, json, gson

I've recently started playing around with `JSON` strings, and was told that Google's own library, `Gson`, is the new and hip way of dealing with these.

The way I've understood it, is that a `JSON` string is essentially a map. Where each variable points to a value in the string.

For example:

```
String jsonInput2 = "{\"created_at\":\"Sat Feb 08 15:37:37 +0000 2014\",\"id\":432176397474623489\"}
```

Thus far, all is well. Information such as when this `JSON` string was created, can be assigned to a variable with the following code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map = (Map<String, String>) gson.fromJson(jsonInput, map.getClass());

String createdAt = map.get("created_at");
```

It's almost artistic in in simple beauty. But this is where the beauty ends and my confusion begins.

The following is an extension of the above `JSON` string;

```
String jsonInput2 = "{\"created_at\":\"Sat Feb 08 15:37:37 +0000 2014\",\"id\":432176397474623489\",\"user\":{\"id_str\":\"366301747\",\"name\":\"somethingClever\",\"screen_name\":\"somethingCoolAndClever\"}}";
```

My question is how these "brackets within brackets" work for the `user` section of the `JSON`?

How could I assign the values specified within these inner-brackets to variables?

Can anyone explain to me, or show me in code, how `Gson` handles stuff like this, and how I can use it?

In short, why does...

```
String jsonInput = "{\"created_at\":\"Sat Feb 08 15:37:37 +0000 2014\",\"id\":432176397474623489\",\"user\":{\"id_str\":\"366301747\",\"name\":\"somethingClever\",\"screen_name\":\"somethingCoolAndClever\"}}";

Gson gson = new Gson();

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map = (Map<String, String>) gson.fromJson(jsonInput, map.getClass());

String name = map.get("name");

System.out.println(name);
```

... print out `null`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Forget about Java. You need to first understand the [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

This is basically it

```
object
    {}
    { members }
members
    pair
    pair , members
pair
    string : value
array
    []
    [ elements ]
elements
    value 
    value , elements
value
    string
    number
    object
    array
    true
    false
    null
```

Your second JSON `String` (which has a missing `"`) is the following (use https://jsonlint.com/ to format)

```json
{
    "created_at": "Sat Feb 08 15:37:37 +0000 2014",
    "id": "432176397474623489",
    "user": {
        "id_str": "366301747",
        "name": "somethingClever",
        "screen_name": "somethingCoolAndClever"
    }
}
```

The JSON is an object, outer `{}`, that contains three pairs, `created_at` which is a JSON string, `id` which is also a JSON string, and `user` which is a JSON object. That JSON object contains three more pairs which are all JSON strings.

You asked

> How could I assign the values specified within these inner-brackets to
> variables?

Most advanced JSON parsing/generating libraries are meant to convert JSON to Pojos and back.

So you could map your JSON format to Java classes.

```
class Pojo {
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private String createdAt;
    private String id;
    private User user;
}

class User {
    @SerializedName("id_str")
    private String idStr;
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("screen_name")
    private String screenName;
}

// with appropriate getters, setters, and a toString() method
```

Note the [`@SerializedName`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/1e7625b963d2e4447a4aa46a2fadc6d0e3a3aba7/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.java) [(JavaDoc)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) so that you can keep using Java naming conventions for your fields.

You can now deserialize your JSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Pojo pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonInput2, Pojo.class);
System.out.println(pojo);
```

would print

```
Pojo [createdAt=Sat Feb 08 15:37:37 +0000 2014, id=432176397474623489, user=User [idStr=366301747, name=somethingClever, screenName=somethingCoolAndClever]]
```

showing that all the fields were set correctly.

> Can anyone explain to me, or show me in code, how Gson handles stuff like this, and how I can use it?

The source code of [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is freely available. You can find it online. It is complex and a source code explanation wouldn't fit here. Simply put, it uses the `Class` object you provide to determine how it will map the JSON pairs. It looks at the corresponding class's fields. If those fields are other classes, then it recurs until it has constructed a map of everything it needs to deserialize.

---

> In short, why does...print out null?

Because your root JSON object, doesn't have a pair with name `name`. Instead of using `Map`, use Gson's `JsonObject` type.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonInput2, JsonObject.class);

String name = jsonObject.get("user")       // get the 'user' JsonElement
                        .getAsJsonObject() // get it as a JsonObject
                        .get("name")       // get the nested 'name' JsonElement
                        .getAsString();    // get it as a String
System.out.println(name);
```

which prints

```
somethingClever
```

The above method class could have thrown a number of exceptions if they weren't the right type. If, for example, we had done

```
String name = jsonObject.get("user")       // get the 'user' JsonElement
                        .getAsJsonArray()  // get it as a JsonArray
```

it would fail because `user` is not a JSON array. Specifically, it would throw

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
    at com.spring.Example.main(Example.java:19)
```

So the [`JsonElement`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/1e7625b963d2e4447a4aa46a2fadc6d0e3a3aba7/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java) [(JavaDoc)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) class (which is the parent class of `JsonObject`, `JsonArray`, and a few others) provides methods to check what it is. See the javadoc.

Comment: The best and easiest to understand answer. Thank you Sotirios!

Comment: @ViRALiC You're welcome. My best advice is to get comfortable with JSON before you look into Gson.

Answer (score 19):

For people that come here searching for a way to **convert LinkedTreeMap to object**:

```
MyClass object = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(((LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) theLinkedTreeMapObject)), MyClass .class)
```

This was usefull for me when i needed to parse an generic object like:

```
Class fullObject {
  private String name;
  private String objectType;
  private Object objectFull;   
}
```

But i don't know which object the server was going to send. The objectFull will become a LinkedTreeMap

Answer (score 6):

The JSON string has following structure:

```
{
    created_at: "",
    id: "",
    user: {
            id_str: "",
            name: "",
            screen_name: ""
    }
 }
```

When you put the values in the map using the code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(jsonInput, map.getClass());
```

It has following key values:

```
created_at
id
user
```

and that's why you are able to use `map.get("created_at")`.

Now, since you want to get the name of the user, you need to get the map of user:

```
LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> userMap = (LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) map.get("user");
```

In the `userMap`, you would get following key values:

```
id_str
name
screen_name
```

Now, you can get the `name` of the `user`

```
String name = userMap.get("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

`user` is a `JsonObject` itself:

```
JsonObject user = map.get("user");
```

Comment: It might be, but this won't work as `map` is declared as `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: No, in this case it will default to `LinkedTreeMap`. Gson doesn't know about `JsonObject` unless you tell it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. First of all JSON is short for "JavaScript Object Notation" so your assertion that "a JSON string is essentially a map" is incorrect. A JSON block is an object graph, described using the JavaScript language syntax. Since your trying to coerce an object graph to a Map of String, Sting kay value pairs, this is only going to work in cases where any given JSON object graph is essentially just that (so not very often). A more successful strategy would probably be `gson.fromJson()` which will convert your JSON to a proper Java object graph.