# Deserialize complex gson - Java

Tags: java, deserialization, gson

I have an array of objects which are like below.

```
{
  "propone": {
    "proponeone": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 1,
      "c": 1
    },
    "proponetwo": {
      "a": 1
    },
    "proponethree": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 1
    },
    "proponethree": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 1,
      "c": 1
    }
  },
  "proptwo": {
    "proptwoone": [
      "val1",
      "val2",
      "val3",
      "val4"
    ],
   "proptwoone": [
      "val5",
      "val6",
      "val7"
    ]
  }
}
```

I read this array to a JsonObject and I want to deserialize this array of objects. I want to put "proptwoone" in to a `HashMap` of type `<String, ArrayList<String>>`. Is there a way to do that? I use Gson.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285661/gson-json-and-the-subtleties-of-linkedtreemap/22285780

Comment: I went through that but it does not have what I need here

Comment: I tried using gson.fromJson directly but it is not working

Comment: First and foremost, that's not a JSON array.  Go to json.org and learn how to read JSON.  It only takes 5 minutes to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON's structure will be always like that, you can try to create a class like this, using a generic `Object` for that part you're not interested in:

```
public class Response {
  public Object propone;
  public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> proptwo;
}
```

Then just parse your JSON with:

```
Response response = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, Response.class);
```

And your `HashMap` will be under:

```
response.proptwo
```

But I guess this won't work if you have duplicated field names `proptwoone`...