# How do I convert a LinkedTreeMap to gson JsonObject

Tags: java, string, gson, json

For a java data handler, I send properly formatted JSON, but a combination of Spring, Java deciding how to cast what it sees, and frameworks I really shouldn't go changing mangle that JSON so that once I can see it, it's turned into a LinkedTreeMap, and I need to transform it into a JsonObject. 
This is not to serialize/de-serialize JSON into java objects, it's "final form" is a gson JsonObject, and it needs to be able to handle literally any valid JSON.

```
{
"key":"value",
"object": {
    "array":[
        "value1", 
        "please work"
        ]
    }
}
```

is the sample I've been using, once I see it, it's a LinkedTreeMap that .toString() s to

```
{key=value, object={array=[value1, please work]}}
```

where you can replace "=" with ":", but that doesn't have the internal quotes for the

```
new JsonParser().parse(gson.toJson(STRING)).getAsJsonObject()
```

strategy.

Is there a more direct way to convert LinkedTreeMap to JsonObject, or a library to add the internal quotes to the string, or even a way to turn a sting into a JsonObject that doesn't need the internal quotes?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285661/gson-json-and-the-subtleties-of-linkedtreemap

Comment: I don't understand. Are you looking to get a `String`? Then just `toJson` passing in the `LinkedTreeMap`.

Comment: I'm looking to get a JsonObject by hook or by crook, having not found any way to go directly from LinkedTreeMap to JsonObject, I've started looking at String manipulation, as there is a proper way to get a string converted to JsonObject.

Comment: How did you get a `LinkedTreeMap` to begin with? Just deserialize directly to `JsonObject`.

Comment: The LinkedTreeMap is what I get from the "combination of Spring, Java deciding how to cast what it sees, and frameworks I really shouldn't go changing" 
The first time I have access to the data it is already a LinkedTreeMap, if you can deserialize LinkedTreeMap directly to JsonObject, that would be the answer to the question.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You'd typically have to serialize the object to JSON, then parse that JSON back into a `JsonObject`. Fortunately, `Gson` provides a [`toJsonTree`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJsonTree-java.lang.Object-) method that kind of skips the parsing.

```
LinkedTreeMap<?,?> yourMap = ...;
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.toJsonTree(yourMap).getAsJsonObject();
```

Note that, if you can, just deserialize the JSON directly to a `JsonObject` with

```
gson.fromJson(theJson, JsonObject.class);
```