# How to Get a specific string from HashMap

Tags: java, android, gson

I'm trying to get a specific value from HashMap.

I converted `JsonObject` into `hashMap` Like this :

```
Map<String, Object> mapObj = new Gson().fromJson(
        jsonObject, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

All great for now.

When I try to get value from the mapObj
like this

```
String strValue = (String) mapObj.get("estimate_time");
```

It give null

My Json is

https://api.myjson.com/bins/16sub7

I really don't know what to do.

Comment: So that tells you that there is no key `"estimate_time"` in the Map. Or, it's there and it actually maps to `null`.

Comment: But i'm sure it is there the server is giving it back as you saw in the json its a response from the server and i tried to get .. its gviing only "data": all info but i can't get specific inside it

Comment: Its not null its estimate_time":"3 mins" in the json file i showed up

Comment: I think this is really a question about what Gson is doing.

Comment: To be honest i'm not sure but i'll try explain what i want
I have this 3 objects in Json 1 of them inside it have strings i need from them estimate_time like i have it already on JsonObject but i can't get the value i tried to convert into map but still i can't get to something.settext="the value i need"

Comment: Add a breakpoint on mapObj and make sure it's not null. if it's not then you're using the wrong key or the value is null.

Comment: Yep i think its the wrong key i hope if someone know how to do it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "estimate_time" isn't a valid key. It's contained inside the value for the key "data".

If you [beautified](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) your json value, you'd be able to notice more clearly that the value for the key "estimate_time" is contained inside the value for the key "data".

To get the value of the "estimated_time" you'll need to access the json value for the key "data", and then access the value for key "estimated_time" from that.

I've never actually worked with `Gson` before, but something along the following lines should work (or at the very least, give you an idea on how to approach the issue)

```
Map<String, Object> mapObj = new Gson().fromJson(
    jsonObject, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());

LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> requiredMapObj = (LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) mapObj.get("data");

String strValue = (String) requiredMapObj.get("estimate_time");

String numberValueAlone = strValue.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285661/gson-json-and-the-subtleties-of-linkedtreemap))

Comment: yep i don't really have an idea how to do that to be honest any help?

Comment: @Dotdat I've never actually worked with `Gson` before, so I'm unable to give you a concrete example. But the idea is fairly simple, You get the Json value for the key "data", construct a map using that and then, access the value for the key "estimate_time" from that.

Comment: Yep i was trying this all day but it keep giving me this

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Oh, I guess `Gson` internally identifies the type for the value. I'll update my answer, check if the new code works.

Comment: I have just 1 more question if you know i get the value which is 3 mins
can i get only the number? which is 3?
and without the {3}

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it and upvote if it works. =)

Comment: Thank you so much its set the text on {=3} I can't take only 3?
so sorry for asking too much

Comment: That's weird, I just did a quick test `System.out.println("={=3 mins}".replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));` prints 3. What value do you get when you print strValue?

Comment: System.out: 3
,
ESTTIME CHECK ::: {=3}
,
Log.d("**ESTTIME CHECK ::", ""+esttime.toString());

Comment: Worked I just did your trick with the settext Thank you so much!

pinTimeTextView.setText(esttime.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that upvote privilege is only unlocked when your reputation reaches 15.