# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast t

Tags: java, spring-boot, retrofit2

I am trying to consume rest service using retrofit2 and it works fine when my pojo does not have a generic type. When I don't use generic everything works fine. Here is my retrofit Service. The error is occurring at the point of iterating over the Array List as shown in the picture in the [This Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT6GJ.png).

```
   public interface EposService 
{
    @POST("v1/api/product/load_product")
    public Call<RestResponseObject> getProducts(@Body ProductParam udata);    

}
public class RestResponseObject<T> {
       public String message;
        private Object payload;
        private boolean responseStatus,status;
        List<T> data;//getter setter
}
public class ProductBean  {

     private String make, manufacture_year, name;//getter setter

}
private static RestResponseObject<ProductBean> findProducts(ProductParam pay) {
         RestResponseObject mv=new RestResponseObject();
          EposService service = retrofit.create(EposService.class);

        final Call<RestResponseObject> call = service.getProducts(pay);

        try {
            Response<RestResponseObject> resp = call.execute();
           if(resp!=null)
                {
            if (resp.code() == 200) {


                       mv=resp.body();

            } 
            else{

               // mv.setStatus(false);//("05");
                //mv.setMessage("connection error");
            }
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return mv;
    }
```

Here is full stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to api.bean.ProductBean
    at retrofit.Exec.main(Exec.java:63)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object being received is being converted into a LinkedTreeMap by your JSON converter, and you shall somehow need to convert it into a ProductBean for you to access it

Comment out the for loop you have and paste the below code below it and see what happens:

```
for(Object b: ps)
{
    ProductBean bean = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(((LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) b)), ProductBean.class);
    System.out.println(bean.getName());
}
```

(Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34122115/3279904) answer)